# Cross compiling with automake

Tags: cross-compiling, gnu, gnu-make, automake

I'm trying to cross compile a project and a library it depends on for use on an embedded system.  Both the application and the dependency use automake.  I was able to compile the library without much issue.

```
./configure --host=powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe --prefix=/home/me/build_dir
make
make install
```

I used `--prefix` so that `make install` didn't put the outputs in my filesystem with all of the x86 libs.  I have also tried running configure without `--prefix` and instead setting the `DESTDIR` environment variable before running `make install`.  They appear to do the same thing.  I want to be able to tar up `/home/me/build_dir` and drop it on the root of the embedded target's file system.  I'm hoping that `--prefix` didn't hard code an absolute path on my host machine somewhere.

Then I tried to cross compile the application that uses this library:

```
./configure --host=powerpc-none-linux-gnuspe --with-sysroot=/home/me/build_dir
```

I ran into 2 things.  The configure script completed successfully but the first make failed because it couldn't find one of the headers.  It is looking under `/usr/include` instead of `/home/be/build_dir/usr/include`.  Shouldn't the `--with-sysroot` option also modify the include directories or am I missing something?

Also, I'm getting a warning

```
libtool: link: warning: library libstdc++.la was moved
```

I get the feeling that I've missed something.  Is this warning something I can safely ignore or did I mess up somewhere?

To summarize my questions:
1) Is there a difference between `./configure --prefix=x` and `make DESTDIR=x install`?
2) What's the right way to update the search path for the library headers?
3) Why am I getting the warning about libstdc++ and is it something I should worry about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your situation you should use `DESTDIR`.  Setting `--prefix` will mean the resulting program will expect to be installed at the location in `--prefix`.  `DESTDIR` on the other hand is a purely make install artifact, it just prefixes that to the beginning of every path when it installs.  The resulting product still expects to be installed at the `--prefix` location.  If you want to install the results on the target host, set `--prefix` to the place it will go and use `DESTDIR` to stage it somewhere else.

I believe that just setting `--sysroot` in the `configure` script is not sufficient, but I'm not sure.  I think that sets the sysroot while `configure` runs but it doesn't set the makefile.

What I usually do is create a shell script wrapper for the compiler which invokes the real compiler with the proper `--sysroot=dir` option, then use that wrapper as the compiler name to `configure`.  It's simpler to do it that way, than to try to get all invocations of the compiler to add the `--sysroot` flag externally.

I'm not sure about the `libstdc++` warning.  `libstdc++` is a part of the compiler, not part of the sysroot...?

ETA:

By script wrapper I mean create a script named something like `sysroot-gcc`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec real-gcc --sysroot=/some/sysroot "$@"
```

then you can run `configure CC=sysroot-gcc`.  You can make this as fancy as you want to; I have a generic script that parses the name (`$0`) and obtains the sysroot name and the tool name (`gcc`, `g++`, etc.) from it so I can reuse that one script for all tools.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful information.  I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the shell script wrapper.